# How to jump to the next keyword and highlight?

Tags: delphi

I have procedure like this:

```
procedure TSomeObj.TestMe(Sender: Tobject)
begin
end;
```

and now I want to convert it to something like this:

```
procedure TSomeObj.TestMe(FileName: string);
begin
end;
```

When I am done overwriting the 'Sender' keyword I would like to jump over the ':' to the next keyword (to 'TObject') and select it, so when I start typing I will totally overwrite it.

I can be done in two steps: Ctrl+RightArrow then Ctrl+K+T. But that's a complicated shortcut. You can barely call it a ***shortcut*** anymore. Is there a better/faster trick to do it?

Comment: Questions about how to use an IDE are perfectly fine here, as IDEs are "tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: In answer to your question, you shouldn't be renaming your procedures and methods that way. Use the IDE's built-in refactoring, which will handle both renaming the method and renaming/retyping the parameters, and will properly update all references to it in your code at the same time. If you're renaming an event handler, do so in the Object Inspector. You can't rename the parameters of an IDE generated event or change the type, because then it doesn't match the definition of the event handler.

Comment: I just double click in/on the next word. And if I have to do repeated editing like this there's always Ctrl-Shift-R and Ctrl-Shift-P.

Comment: @KenWhite - I know. I gave a bad example. I changed the original question.

Comment: I didn't say "break the IDE". I said you'd get compile errors because the definitions don't match. Why are you nitpicking with some nonsense when people are trying to help you?

Comment: About "nitpicking": the 'nit' in my my question was not about what will happen with the IDE if I change the declaration of Button1Click. Was about a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can just use CTRL+T to delete the next word and start typing. Overall, the refactoring method should be faster though.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - Ctrl+T will delete also the column (:). But is is better than Ctrl+RightArrow, Ctrl+K+T

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers-Actually it works pretty nice. Thanks. If you post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> twice to delete the <kbd>:</kbd> and next word and start typing your replacement.

*Overall, the refactoring method would be faster though.*

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer.